# Sitecore experience editor button triggering .aspx pop up page

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, experience-editor

Is it possible to make sitecore experience editor ribbon button trigger `.aspx` page in pop up window? It was possible before `speak-ui` was introduced by assigning a command to the button's `click` field.

There is a lot of tutorials describing how to use XML controls (e.g. http://jockstothecore.com/sitecore-8-ribbon-button-transfiguration/) but I can't find any information about triggering `.aspx` page.

My command looks like this:
`<command name="item:showDashboard" type="Sitecore.Starterkit.customcode.Reports, MyProject" />`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the tutorial you posted I will just modify the code snippets to reflect what you need to do. (Considering you have done everything else). In the part `Spell Two`

In the command class you should do something like this (if you need to wait for postback):

```
        public override void Execute(CommandContext context)
        {
          Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) context, "context");
          Context.ClientPage.Start((object) this, "Run", context.Parameters);
        }

        protected static void Run(ClientPipelineArgs args)
        {
            Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object) args, "args");

            SheerResponse.ShowModalDialog(new UrlString("/YOURURL.aspx").ToString(), true);
            args.WaitForPostBack();          
        }
```

If you just want to show something :

```
        public override void Execute(CommandContext context)
        {

            Assert.ArgumentNotNull((object)context, "context");
            if (context.Items.Length != 1)
                return;
            Item obj = context.Items[0];
            UrlString urlString = new UrlString("/YOURURL.aspx");
            urlString["fo"] = obj.ID.ToString();
            urlString["la"] = obj.Language.ToString();
            urlString["vs"] = obj.Version.ToString();
            string str = "location=0,menubar=0,status=0,toolbar=0,resizable=1,getBestDialogSize:true";
            SheerResponse.Eval("scForm.showModalDialog('" + (object)urlString + "', 'SitecoreWebEditEditor', '" + str + "');");
        }
```

For the javascript:

```
define(["sitecore"], function (Sitecore) {
    Sitecore.Commands.ScoreLanguageTools = {
        canExecute: function (context) {
            return true; // we will get back to this one
        },
        execute: function (context) {
            var id = context.currentContext.itemId;
            var lang = context.currentContext.language;
            var ver = context.currentContext.version;

            var path = "/YOURURL.aspx?id=" + id + "&lang=" + lang + "&ver=" + ver;

            var features = "dialogHeight: 600px;dialogWidth: 500px;";

            Sitecore.ExperienceEditor.Dialogs.showModalDialog(
                path, '', features, null, 
                function (result) {
                    if (result) {
                        window.top.location.reload();
                    }
                }
            );
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I have already figured it. I haven't tested your solution but since your approach looks the same I'll mark it as the correct answer.